# How fast can Captain Marvel travel in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-marvel

At the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame* Tony Stark is drifting in space and in the recorded message he says he's "1000 lightyears" from Earth. Captain Marvel shows up and next thing we know Danvers is gracefully putting the ship down on Earth.

As the ship was non-functional as far as we could tell and unable to jump through wormholes on its own, how did they get back so fast? Can Captain Marvel jump through wormholes while carrying a space ship?

Comment: Yes. Obviously she can

Comment: Idk but the “a thousand light years away” is most likely a figure of speech. Remember, the MCU hasn’t established the exact location of Titan

Comment: As Ebony Maw, having captured Dr. Strange, was leaving the Earth with its ring-shaped ship in _Avengers: Infinity War_ towards the Titan, the ship did _a_ jump, so it is at least some distance away.

Comment: Perhaps she could restore power to the ship and it could then open the wormhole.   She has those glowy hands.

Comment: In the movie at one point she flies from the ground to space to fight some Accuser vessels attacking the planet. Let's assume that it took less than an hour for her to reach the ships (which seems like a safe estimate). Let's also assume the Accuser ships were in high orbit, so let's say 35,786 kilometers high above her. Assuming that she covered that distance in 59 minutes, that means that she can fly at least as fast as 10,109 m/s or 22,613 mph.

Answer (score 5):

Carol can travel insanely fast. The fastest on screen example of this we see is at the end of *Captain Marvel* when she leaves Earth with the Skrulls and can easily keep up with the ship going at what appears to be lightspeed.

However, we know she can't travel instantaneously so there is some cap to her speed. We know this from the fact that she used the comms system in the meeting with Nat on Earth in *Avengers: Endgame* whilst she's out helping other planets. If she could just teleport surely she'd be there in person.

> **Carol Danvers:** Listen, fur-face, I’m covering a lot of territory out here. The things that have been happening on Earth have been happening everywhere else. On thousands of planets. You might not see me for a long time.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Of course she can also use the jump points we see dotted around the galaxy as we first see in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*. We also see that there is one on Earth in *Captain Marvel*. These would cut her travel times down significantly.

Also note that we don't see the full journey of Carol saving Tony/Nebula, for obvious reasons. She appears in front of the Benatar, we get a jump cut and they're landing on Earth. There is no indication for how long it took.

Putting this together we see that she can travel quickly and she has access to travel even faster by using the jump points. However, we don't know how fast she can actually travel, there is no figure to it and no way of really estimating it from what we see on screen.

Comment: "insanely fast" you Americans will do what you can to avoid using the metric system huh? :-p

Comment: Isn't the point that she _is_ the lightspeed engine?

Comment: @Möoz _”you Americans”_ - you take that back! I am British thank you very much. And she’s not the lightspeed engine for the Skrull’s ship but I suppose you could argue she is her own one.

Comment: So wait, the ex-Kree, now Skrull ship is Lightspeed powered? You sure? I thought Mar-Vell was still working on it when she died?

Answer (score 4):

### Unknown

This isn't even a stat known in the comics. There are quite a few references to *Captain Marvel Vol. 7 #8* where she was apparently clocked as going [Mach 3 for a few hours](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Carol_Danvers_(Earth-616)#Powers_and_Abilities), though I have not been able to confirm this. But realistically speaking, she has no canonical top speed, and can travel at the [Speed of Plot](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TravelingAtTheSpeedOfPlot).

Comment: A TV Tropes link? Well that's my day all shot to hell :p